# EditText space between the line and the input

Tags: android

Hi I was just wondering how to remove the space between the text and the input line on an edittext field?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edittext design is based on .9.png file (more on 9 patch [there](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)) available in android sdk resources (../sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res), there is an example of it (Android 5.0 edittext background) :

[image: Material Design edittext]

As you can see the space between text and input line (biggest black line) is part of the image, so to change it you have create your own edittext background and apply it to your app edittext (simply with a style).